# Entity framework LINQ where attribute equals of ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a class "A" that contains a ICollection of "B".
I want to select "A" including all "B" that the status equals "active". I'm trying this, but it's not working, it's returning inactive records of B:

```
        return MyContext.A
              .Where(t => t.B.Any(b => b.Status.Equals("active")))
              .Include(b => b.B);
```

I already tried adding this:

```
Where(b => b.B.Select(x => x.Status).Equals("active"))
```

but I get an exception "cannot compare elements of type ienumerable"

Answer (score 1):

You can't `Include` navigation property items that match given predicate. `Include` always includes the entire collection.

You'd have to query your data into a separate class or anonymous item:

```
var results = context.A.Select(a => new { A = a, B = a.B.Where(b => b.Status == "Actuve") });
```

Comment: Hi! Ok...Where I add the "Include" and convert it to a IEnumerable<A> ? Or how can I return the results?

Comment: You can't. `A` returned and tracked by EF will always have either no `B` items, or all of them.